# Client and Object Class outputting values

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have an object and client class created which prints coordinates in order of their distance from the origin. The client class asks the user how many dimensions they want the array to have (x,y or x,y,z) how many points they want generated, and a range from which each coordinate will run from (ex. -x to x, -y to y etc.). When I run the program it prints out the correct number of points, but there is always one extra element in the array (etc. when user enters dimension of array as '4', it always prints out one extra element -> [4, 5, 9, 6, 1]). Why is this happening?

Client Class

```
    import java.io.*;   

public class MA {  

  public MA() { }   

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 

    String myString = "arrayNumPoints.txt";
    int numpoints = 0;
    int dimension = 0;
    double lengthscale = 0;
    double [][] points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1]; 

    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    MB pointsB = new MB(); 

    System.out.println("Enter number of points:"); 
    String numpointsA = myInput.readLine(); 
    numpoints = Integer.parseInt(numpointsA); 
    pointsB.setnumpoints(numpoints); 

    System.out.println("Enter the dimension:"); 
    String dimensionA = myInput.readLine(); 
    dimension = Integer.parseInt(dimensionA); 
    pointsB.setdim(dimension); 

    System.out.println("Enter length(range):"); 
    String lengthscaleA = myInput.readLine(); 
    lengthscale = Double.parseDouble(lengthscaleA); 
    pointsB.setlengthscale(lengthscale); 


    pointsB = new MB(numpoints, lengthscale, dimension, points);

    pointsB.fillarray(pointsB.getarray(), pointsB.getlengthscale(), pointsB.getdim(), pointsB.getnumpoints());
    pointsB.caldistance(pointsB.getarray(), pointsB.getnumpoints(), pointsB.getdim());
    pointsB.sort(pointsB.getarray(), 0, pointsB.getnumpoints()-1, pointsB.getdim());
    pointsB.writefile(pointsB.getarray(), pointsB.getnumpoints(), myString);
    pointsB.readfile(myString);
  }
}
```

Object Class

```
    import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class MB { 

  //variables and arrays are declared
  private double lengthscale; 
  private int numpoints; 
  private int dimension; 
  private double [][] points; 

  //constructor
  public MB() { }   

  //constructor
  public MB(double [][] points) { 
    numpoints = 0; 
    lengthscale = 0; 
    dimension = 0; 
    points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1]; 
  }   

  //constructor
  public MB(int mynumpoints, double mylengthscale, int mydimension, double [][] mypoints) { 
    numpoints = mynumpoints; 
    lengthscale = mylengthscale; 
    dimension = mydimension; 
    points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1]; 
  }   

  //numpoints getter
  public int getnumpoints() 
  { 
    return numpoints; 
  }   

  //numpoints setter
  public void setnumpoints(int mynumpoints) { 
    numpoints = mynumpoints; 
  }   

  //lengthscale getter
  public double getlengthscale() { 
    return lengthscale; 
  }   

  //lengthscale setter
  public void setlengthscale(double mylengthscale) { 
    lengthscale = mylengthscale; 
  }   

  //dimension getter
  public int getdim() { 
    return dimension; 
  }  

  //dimension setter
  public void setdim(int mydimension) { 
    dimension = mydimension; 
  }   

  //array getter
  public double[][] getarray() { 
    return points; 
  }   

  //array setter
  public void setarray(double [][]mypoints, int numpoints, int dimension) { 
    points[numpoints][dimension] = mypoints[numpoints][dimension];
  }   

  //fill array method
  public void fillarray(double [][]mypoints, double mylengthscale, int mydimension, int mynumpoints) throws IOException { 

    for(int x = 0; x < mynumpoints; x++) 
    { 
      for(int y = 0; y < mydimension; y++) {
        //fills array with random points within the specified range
        mypoints[x][y] = (dimension * Math.random() - 1) * mylengthscale;   
      }//end for   
    }//end for
  }

  //writefile method
  public void writefile(double [][]mypoints, int mynumpoints, String myString) throws IOException { 

    //writes to myString
    PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(myString));

    //for loop runs for length of mylengthscale
    for(int m = 0; m < mynumpoints; m++) {
      //prints points to file
      fileOut.println(Arrays.toString(mypoints[m]));   
    }
      //close file
      fileOut.close(); 
    //end for
  }

  //readfile metod
  public void readfile(String myString) throws IOException 
  { 
    String filePath = myString; 
    //reads data from mString
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(myString))); 
    String line = null; 

    while(( (line = in.readLine()) != null)) 

    System.out.println(line);   
    in.close(); 
  }  


  //caldistance method
  public void caldistance(double [][]mypoints, int mynumpoints, int mydimension) { 

    //for loop; calculates distance for specified number of points
    for(int i = 0; i < mynumpoints; i++) { 
      for(int k = 0; k < mydimension; k++) { 
        mypoints[i][mydimension] = mypoints[i][k] * mypoints[i][k];
      }//end for loop
      mypoints[i][mydimension] = Math.sqrt(mypoints[i][mydimension]); 
    }//end for loop                              
  }

  //sort method
  public double[][] sort(double[][] mynewpoints, int down, int top, int mydimension) {

    System.arraycopy(mynewpoints, 0, mynewpoints, 0, mynewpoints.length);

    //variables are declared
    int d = down;
    int u = top;

    //determines pivot point

    double [] pivot = mynewpoints[(down + top)/2];


    //sorts the values of the array, comparing it to the pivot
   do {
      while (mynewpoints[d][mydimension] < pivot[mydimension]) {
        d++;
      }

      while (mynewpoints[u][mydimension] > pivot[mydimension]) {
        u--;
      }

      if (d <= u) {
        double[] temporary = new double[mynewpoints[d].length];

        //compres values in array and switches them     
        for (int y = 0; y < mynewpoints[d].length; y++) {
          temporary[y] = mynewpoints[d][y];
          mynewpoints[d][y] = mynewpoints[u][y];
          mynewpoints[u][y] = temporary[y];
        }
        d++;
        u--;
      }
    } while (d <= u);

    if (down < u) {
      mynewpoints = sort(mynewpoints, mydimension, down, u);
    }

    if (d < top) {
      mynewpoints = sort(mynewpoints, mydimension, d, top);
    }

    return mynewpoints;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific (show us the code fragments, which you use and which go wrong).

However do you realize, that in your MB constructor :

```
  //constructor
  public MB(double [][] points) { 
    numpoints = 0; 
    lengthscale = 0; 
    dimension = 0; 
    points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1]; 
  }
```

The last line is not doing anything? You have to write it like this :

```
this.points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1];
```

Because you have two variables `points`, one is class variable, second is passed as parameter. If this happens, without using `this` the non-class variable is chosen.

Comment: i added `this` where you have mentioned. Now when I run the program, I am getting the error saying 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at MB.sort(MultidimensionalB.java:144)
 at MB.sort(MultidimensionalB.java:171)
 at MA.main(MultidimensionalA.java:39)`

line 144 : `while (mynewpoints[d][mydimension] < pivot[mydimension]) {`
line 171: `mynewpoints = sort(mynewpoints, mydimension, d, top);`
 and line 39 is where i call the sort method in the client class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're adding `1` to the dimension given by the user:

```
points = new double[numpoints][dimension + 1];
```

This results in the array having one more column than value of `dimension`.

Comment: the reason why i have  `+ 1` is because i am storing the distance in that spot.